# C#: Read a stream from a file

Tags: c#, stream, filestream

I have a stream saved to a file the following way:

```
public void SaveTest(DataObject data)
{
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), data.Descriptor.Name);
    var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(fullPath, ".content"), FileMode.CreateNew);
    data.Content.CopyTo(fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();
    var information = new XElement("Test Information",
                                        new XAttribute("Name", data.Descriptor.Name),
                                        new XAttribute("Description", data.Descriptor.Description),
                                        new XAttribute("Owner", data.Descriptor.Owner)
                                        );
    information.Save(Path.Combine(fullPath, ".information"));
}
```

`DataObject` contains a stream which is the test's content and a descriptor with 3 fields I'd like to save.
Now I need a method to read those files, and I need to read the `.content` file as a stream, not string. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can *open* it as a stream as simply as:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    ...
}
```

Or you can read the whole lot as a byte array:

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

(You can then wrap that in a `MemoryStream` if you want.)

Comment: Hi, I have a related question if you don't mind answering - After saving the stream using a file stream, when I read it and compare the two streams (using `Assert`), they are not equal. Do you know why?

Comment: @Noich: `Stream` doesn't override `Equals`. If you want to compare the contents, you'll need to read the data and compare that.